# Angular error in Firefox only "Multiple directives asking for isolated scope"

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/oRUbINE/2/edit) to illustrate the issue.

When using [tooltip from the Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip) on an element which is also using directive that asks for an isolated scope, eg:

```
.directive('smile', function() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    template: ':)'
  };
});
```

I get the following error in Firefox but not in Chrome:

> Error: Multiple directives [smile, tooltip] asking for isolated scope
>   on: <a class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope" href="#" tooltip="Tooltip"
>   tooltip-placement="bottom" smile="">

Which is odd because I wouldn't expect a tooltip to ask for an isolated scope. It's my understanding [this line in the source](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js#L110) says that the directive does **not** ask for an isolated scope, and that only [the popup](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.js#L328) which gets injected at the bottom of the page does.

What am I missing here? Why is this error only showing up in Firefox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Line of Code you mentioned says

> restrict: 'EA',
>
> ```
>     scope: true,
>
>     link: function link ( scope, element, attrs ) {
>       var tooltip = $compile( template )( scope );
>       var transitionTimeout;
>       var popupTimeout;
> ```
>
> .....

Setting scope true also creates a *new* scope, which prototypically inherits from the scope of the parent.
[Google group]

So here when you do

> scope : {},

Also create a new scope, but isolated. So two scope for the same

> < a >

And you can have only one scope per element.

For Firefox issue refer :
Isolated scope unicity assertion on same element works on Chrome, fails on Firefox
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3208

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's obviously the same problem. I'm not sure why it was closed without being resolved though.

I understand that you can only have one *isolated* scope per element, but are you sure that you can only have one scope of **any** kind? If so then why would this error only occur in Firefox?

Comment: The issue here is that first with tooltip, you tried creating a inherited new scope, and then with smile directive you overwrote the scope with isolated scope(may be i don't know exactly this assertion might have failed in firefox), if you really want to use both directives, create scope: true for smile directive. Things will work.

Comment: Alright, I'll begrudgingly give you the check mark, but I'm still not clear on whether it's okay to have one isolated scope and other child scopes.